# Como puedo hacer para que al momento de insertar datos en una tabla no me permita ingresar registro doble?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Este es mi procedimiento para generar registros en mi tabla vehiculos

```
PROCEDURE pr_crear_vehiculos(p_nropadron VEHICULOS.NROPADRON%TYPE,p_placa VEHICULOS.PLACA%TYPE , p_motor VEHICULOS.MOTOR%TYPE, 
                             p_serie VEHICULOS.SERIE%TYPE, p_anhofrabricacion VEHICULOS.ANHOFABRICACION%TYPE, p_pasajerossentados VEHICULOS.PASAJEROSSENTADOS%TYPE, 
                             p_pasajerospie VEHICULOS.PASAJEROSPIE%TYPE, p_idvehmodelo VEHICULOS.IDVEHMODELO%TYPE,p_idvehmarca VEHICULOS.IDVEHMARCA%TYPE, p_idvehcategoria VEHICULOS.IDVEHCATEGORIA%TYPE,
                             p_uso VEHICULOS.USO%TYPE, p_usercreate VEHICULOS.USERCREATE%TYPE, p_datecreate VEHICULOS.DATECREATE%TYPE, p_usermodify VEHICULOS.USERMODIFY%TYPE,
                             p_datemodify VEHICULOS.DATEMODIFY%TYPE) AS
  vehiculo_id number;   
  BEGIN
    -- TAREA: Se necesita implantación para PROCEDURE PKG_CV_CRUD_VEHICULOS.PR_CREAR_VEHICULOS
    SELECT MAX(idvehiculo)+1 into vehiculo_id  FROM vehiculos;
    INSERT INTO vehiculos(nropadron, estado, placa, motor, serie, anhofabricacion, pasajerossentados, pasajerospie, idvehmodelo, idvehmarca, idvehcategoria, uso, usercreate, datecreate, usermodify, 
    datemodify)
    VALUES(p_nropadron, 1, p_placa, p_motor, p_serie, p_anhofrabricacion, p_pasajerossentados, p_pasajerospie, p_idvehmodelo, p_idvehmarca, p_idvehcategoria, 
           p_uso, p_usercreate, p_datecreate, p_usermodify, p_datemodify);  
  END PR_CREAR_VEHICULOS;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suponiendo que quieres evitar un número de padrón duplicado, debieras crear un constraint para obligar a que sea único:

```
ALTER TABLE vehiculos ADD CONSTRAINT identificador_unico UNIQUE(p_nropadron)
```

Esto también puedes hacerlo para combinaciones de campos

```
ALTER TABLE vehiculos ADD CONSTRAINT identificador_unico UNIQUE(p_nropadron, p_placa)
```

Ahora tu inserción tirará una excepción que puedes manejar:

```
BEGIN
    SELECT MAX(idvehiculo)+1 into vehiculo_id  FROM vehiculos;
    INSERT INTO vehiculos(...) VALUES(...);  
EXCEPTION
    WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('No se insertará: ya existe ese vehículo')
END PR_CREAR_VEHICULOS;
```

También puedes manejar la excepción haciendo que el registro se actualice, pero no sé si sea lo que quieres.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta la utilizaré justo quería esta respuesta